# Recursion expression to express running time of pseudo code that finds number of instances of int K in array of ints Arr

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Pseudo Code

```
Algorithm: findInstances(Arr, k)
    if Arr.length = 0 then return 0
    if Arr[0] = k then return 1+findInstances(Arr.slice(1), k)
    return findInstances(Arr.slice(1), k)
```

Im looking for T(n) which I would then solve for using induction. I was thinking 
[image]

Comment: The running time of this depends _entirely_ on how efficient you assume the `Arr.slice(1)` operation is.

Comment: But if Im using induction cant I just give a variable as the constant?

Comment: x @yako: Do you have reason to think that `Arr.slice(1)` actually runs in _constant_ time? Since it's pseudocode, it is not very clear precisely what it does, and whether it is reasonable to expect it to be implemented in constant time.

Comment: Yes Im assuming it is constant time